# Manager multiple mvn versions(installations)

Tags: java, shell, maven

Is there a tool like jenv, in favor of manage multiple mvn versions(installations)? the problem is that the first version was developed with mvn 3.0.5 and the second version will be develop with mvn 3.3 so when we compile with a on the command line it shows some mvn methods undefined.

Comment: mvn3.3 should be able to build a 3.0.5-compatible POM.

Comment: Maven 3.3.1 or Maven 3.3.9 are compatbile with Maven 3.0.5 if you have correctly pinned all versions of plugins in your build...

Comment: There is a general `update-alternatives` tool on Linux that allows to use multiple installations of any program. Just google `update-alternatives mvn`.

Answer (score 1):

Looking for the solution, i found the [mvnvm](http://mvnvm.org/) project, it should manage the maven version using the property file **mvnvm.properties** an set it to an specific version:

```
$ cat mvnvm.properties
mvn_version=3.0.5
```